# asyncio with multiprocessing

Tags: python, postgis, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a multiprocessing on a zonal statistic in pure Python. I am new on it.  I have to apply a zonal statistic with a shapefile with more than 6 million features on a taster of 6 GBs (dimension X: 639760 Y: 452420 ). 
I am implemented a multiprocessing starting from this script [this script](https://github.com/csc-training/geocomputing/blob/master/python/zonal_stats/zonal_stats_parallel.py) (from @Perrygeo!!) but the process run forever; after two weeks it haven't finished yet.

The process was reading the entire shapefile and the entire raster and after this processing using the code.

So I would like to implement this process:

- reading the shapefile piece by piece from a `PostGIS` database. I am not able to read a shapefile piece by piece with `geopandas` or `fiona`.
- applying the zonal statistic only on the part intersecting the raster, a very big raster (6.3 GB also with LZW compression). I am assuming the processing will be done only on the intersection area.
- printing the final output on the database

Can I use `asyncio` to implement a concurrency to speed the process and applying at the same time a multiprocessing on the zonal statistic itself?
I need to write a fast code...

Comment: Why can't you do it inn fiona or geopandas. Which zonal statistics, intersecting what raster (very big is not very helpful). What is the input? There are lots of ways to use concurrency depending on the algorithm, input, etc, but your question as it stands is a bit unclear.

Comment: you are right. I will try to write my question better

Comment: Are you planning on loading the the raster to Postgis also? If you load it with tiling, raster2pgsql -t, then vector/raster lookups with us a spatial index and can be very fast. If you are not, then I assume you are opening the raster using something like rasterio in Python?

Comment: Yes I am planning to use rasterio. If I use `raster2pgsql -t` can I read the raster with python ? postgis on zonal statistic is realy slow.

Comment: Yes, you can still read the raster from Postgis, but, if you are using raster2pgsql then there would be no point. My guess is that the reason you are saying that zonal statistics is really slow in Postgis is that you have not tiled your raster. Why can you not read a shapefile bit by bit in Python, btw? As I see it, you could do this either completely in Python or completely in Postgis, it, is the combination that seems to be causing confusion/speed problems.

Comment: yeas, I have to do it in pure python since the process will be repeated several times and for what I saw the raster2pgsql is super slow uploading on postigis.. I am not able to read only one piece on the shape file with python.. I have to upload all the file in memory..

Comment: So, the answer to you question is that you can use asyncio to pick up individual polygons from Postgis and create zonal statistics based on subsets of the numpy array -- which is what the image will be, once loaded by rasterio. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yeas, splitting the shapefile into littler Geo Dataframe,  processing them with asyncio and writing the final Geo Dataframe on Postgis.. I dunno if there is a faster way..